# Promises inside loop to wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have this code:

```
var services = ['EC2', 'S3', 'RDS', 'IAM']
var promises = [];

for(var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
   var promise = awsStatus('us-east-1', services[i])
      promises.push(promise);
      console.log(promises);
}

q.all(promises).then(function(data){
   console.log(promises);
});
```

it's supposed to loop on the `services` array with the `awsStatus` method. The problem is that sometimes I get all the results I want:

```
{ service: 'IAM', status: 0 }
{ service: 'EC2', status: 0 }
{ service: 'RDS', status: 0 }
```

But sometimes I get incomplete results. I thought I needed `.then` after `awsStatus` but that also didn't resolve this. What else is wrong in this piece of code?

since now there's a comment, I've also tried this :

```
var services = ['EC2', 'S3', 'RDS', 'IAM']
var promises = [];

for(var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
   var promise = awsStatus('us-east-1', services[i]).then(function(promise){
      promises.push(promise);
      //console.log(promises);
});
}
q.all(promises).then(function(data){
   console.log(promises);
});
```

and it produces the same results.

Comment: `awsStatus('us-east-1', item).then(function(promise) {
      promises.push(promise);
})`

and make sure   `awsStatus` this should return promise

Comment: I've also tried that but still get the same results.

Comment: Then try this async library (https://github.com/caolan/async). It provides pretty intuitive ways of handling asynchronous situations like this

Comment: I wouldn't just add yet another external library - this is a simple case that should be solved easily. However, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do - logging the promises array would just display the promise objects, not their results. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I think this is simple too. not sure why it doesn't work. I'm trying to run awsStatus for each of those elements in the services array, wait for all the results and display them.

Comment: The output you attached is the actual output you get from that code? This seems odd to me - you should get just an array of Promise objects, not their results

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.each](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#eachfunction-iterator---promise)

```
Promise.each(services, function(service) {
  return awsStatus('us-east-1', service).then(function(promise){
      promises.push(promise);
      //console.log(promises);
  });
}).then(function() {
  console.log('Done with all instances');
});
```

Comment: I tried that and got some random error which I think is related to the `aws-status` module : ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined```

Comment: Yes, that's related to awsStatus

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest a solution using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library as follows:

```
var services = ['EC2', 'S3', 'RDS', 'IAM']
async.map(services, 
  function(item, done){
    awsStatus('us-east-1', item).then(
      function(){
        done(null, "Completed item " + item);
      }, 
      function(err){
        done(err + " in item " + item, null);
      }
    );
  }, 
  function(err, results){
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(results);
  }
);
```

It will fail and stop executing if one of the promises returns an error. If dont want to stop you can return `null` in the error function of promise instead of error message as the first argument of `done` method

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code:

1. Using `q.all()` does not guarantee that the code will wait for all the promises to resolve. If one of them is rejected, the `then` method would be called, not waiting for the rest of the promises. You can solve that by using `q.allResolved()` instead.
2. You are logging the wrong objects. You should be logging the results of the promises, and not the promise objects themselves.

Example of how to solve both problems:

```
q.allResolved(promises).then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: I've tried `allSettled()` as well and got an empty array when logging the results.

Comment: Was `awsStatus` implemented by you, or is it some library?

Comment: I changed it to use `allResolved`, and added a catch. Try it now - if something is rejected, it should show you the error.